# What is the difference between "Learn" and "Ignore" in spell checkers

Tags: pages, spellcheck, sublimetext

When right-clicking a word in Pages and Sublime Text, the user is offered to either "Learn" or "Ignore" the word.

What is the difference between learning and ignoring? To me it would seem the same, that the word is simply "accepted" by the spell-checker and not highlighted as incorrect (red) anymore.

But since it's two different choices, there's obviously a difference. Couldn't find information about this anywhere.

Comment: A guess would be .. ignore = this time, learn = every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Learn" means you are teaching this word to the machine so it knows the word for the future and even suggests you the word if you type it slightly wrong in the future.

"Ignore" means that the machine still does not know the word, but does only not highlight it as wrong anymore in this specific case when you selected "ignore".

Answer (score 1):

By clicking learn it will add it to the dictionary.
If you click ignore it will accept (ignore) it for the current text but not for any other (e.g. new) document.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this matters, I learned the hard way, is you can fill up your dictionary with 'learn', which takes up space on the computer and seems quite hard for the computer shop to figure out when you are plumb out of memory.

Comment: Seriously, how many words did you add? Even assuming a very generous 1 Kilobyte for each word entry, you'd need over 1 million words to make just 1 Gigabyte.